# Measure the closest distance - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I need to find the closest distance between these 2 ellipses.
Is there any method that I can find that using a code?

Thank you.
[image]

Here is my code.

```
    #Elliptical orbits

import pygame
import math
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Elliptical orbit")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while(True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    xRadius = 250
    yRadius = 100
    x2Radius = 100
    y2Radius = 50

    for degree in range(0,360,10):
        x1 = int(math.cos(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * xRadius) + 300
        y1 = int(math.sin(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * yRadius) + 150
        x2 = int(math.cos(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * x2Radius) + 300
        y2 = int(math.sin(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * y2Radius) + 150
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), [300, 150], 35)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 255, 255), [50, 50, 500, 200], 1)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 0, 255), [200, 100, 200, 100], 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), [x1, y1], 15)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 255), [x2, y2], 5)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(5)
```

Comment: This is more a math than a programming question and therefore not really on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Rabbid76 What I need is, when blue circle and the pink circle are closest to each other, the distance between them.

Comment: @KlausD. I thought that there might be a way to get that using coding.

Comment: Your ellipse are axis aligned, have the same center point and specified by `[50, 50, 500, 200]` , `[200, 100, 200, 100]` respectively. Finding the closest point between 2 arbitrary ellipses is a hard task [The closest point from ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315283/the-closest-point-from-ellipse). Do the ellipses always have the same center point?

Comment: @Rabbid76 no. 2 ellipses have different center points.

Comment: "Coding" is the technical implementation of the math you have to do first. No math, no code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from (`x1`, `y1`) to (`x2`, `y2`) can be calculated as follows:

```py
import math

dx = x2-x1
dy = y2-y1
distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

or

```py
distance = math.hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

Comment: May be I can calculate dx and dy for each degree (from 0-360) and get the Euclidean distance for each degree and get  the minimum value. Thank you.